# How to assign an Enum to a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, enums, constructor

I have an input which looks like this:

```
VadaszToni 45
Elephant helyszin1 datum1 23 45
Elephant helyszin1 datum1 56 82
Elephant helyszin1 datum2 89 110
Elephant helyszin2 datum1 99 2
Rhino helyszin1  datum3 120 45
Rhino helyszin1 datum3 12 21
Rhino helyszin1 datum3 98 99
Lion helyszin3 datum4 12 male
Lion helyszin3 datum4 65 male
Lion helyszin3 datum4 120 female
Lion helyszin3 datum5 200 male
Lion helyszin3 datum5 250 male
Lion helyszin3 datum5 2 female
```

And the class

```
class Animals {



protected:                  
    std::string elejtés_helye;
    std::string elejtés_ideje;
    int súly;        
    int plusz_adat;   

    Animals(const std::string& hely, const std::string& idő, int tomeg, int pluszadat) :elejtés_helye(hely), elejtés_ideje(idő), súly(tomeg),plusz_adat(pluszadat) {};

public:
    virtual std::string fajta() = 0;
    virtual Animals* current() = 0;

};

class Elephant : public Animals {

public:
    Elephant(const std::string& hely, const std::string& idő, int tomeg, int elefant_szarv):Animals(hely,idő,tomeg,elefant_szarv) {};

    std::string fajta() override { return "Elephant"; };
    Elephant* current() override { return this; };

};


class Rhino : public Animals {

public:
    Rhino(const std::string& hely, const std::string& idő, int tomeg, int orszarvu_szarva) :Animals(hely, idő, tomeg, orszarvu_szarva) {};

    std::string fajta() override { return "Rhino"; };
    Rhino* current() override { return this; };

};

class Lion : public Animals {

public:
    Lion(const std::string& hely, const std::string& idő, int tomeg, const std::string& oroszlan_neme) {

        elejtés_helye = hely;
        elejtés_ideje = idő;

        if (oroszlan_neme=="male")
        {
            plusz_adat = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            plusz_adat = 2;
        }

    };


    std::string fajta() override { return "Lion"; };
    Lion* current() override { return this; };

};
```

I would like to store the data in an Animal vector, and the most dofficult part for me is to figure out how to store the fifth element. 
In The Lion line, the compiler says "`no default constructor exists for class "Animals`"
Someone recommended me to use Enumes but i dont know how to assign Enum like

```
enum Data{
data1,data2,data3
}
```

(data1 for Elephant 5th input, data2 for Rhino 5th input, data3 for Lion 5th input)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Lion` constructor should read:

```
Lion(const std::string& hely, const std::string& idő, int tomeg, const std::string& oroszlan_neme) :
    Animals(hely, idő, tomeg, oroszlan_neme) { ...
```

(like you did for `Rhino` and `Elephant`).

Also, I see no purpose to the `current()` method and I don't understand your question's title.